# Is it legal to book 2 different flights; 1 earlier & 1 later?

Tags: air-travel

I have a flight booking which owing to the connection time, I may not make.

Initially, I was going to simply change the booking through the airline.

However, the cost to rebook to the next flight, is very similar to the cost of simply booking a ticket on the next flight.

Is there anything to stop me retaining my first booking, just in case I make it, but have the separare booking, in reserve, should I miss the first one?

Comment: you could always book the second ticket on another airline.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I noticed that the particular flight was a codeshare, so have made a reservation with the 'other' airline, so that it wouldn't be as obvious to the original airline. I will end up wasting one or the other but would hate to make the earlier flight, only to not be able to catch it and be late for work.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a question of legal, but what the airline allows, and [this is often not permitted](https://thepointsguy.com/2017/08/illegal-book-2-flights-cancel-1/). For example, United's contract of carriage says:

> The types of improper reservations that UA will cancel without notice include, but are not limited to … reservations made for the same passenger on flights traveling on or about the same date between one or more of the same or nearby origin or destination cities; and reservations with connections that depart before the arrival on the inbound flight.

The airline's revenue protection system may automatically cancel the duplicate booking at some point.

Also, if you have checked bags, they won't follow you to your second booking.

Comment: Thank you. One flight is at 03:30 the next flight is at 07:25. 3H40 duration. However, we wouldn't have bags. Where would I look to find details for that particular airline?

Comment: That talks about _reservations_, not _bookings_. If you _pay_ both tickets, and don't expect money back, it should be in the airline's best interest to take both payments.